# How does a linear operator having constant eigenvalues imply integrability of its eigenvector distribution?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, lie-algebras

I am reading a paper where the authors have constructed a linear operator, say $A$, on vector fields.  They claim that this operator having locally constant eigenvalues is enough to imply that the distribution generated by the eigenvectors of $A$ is integrable.  I am having trouble understanding this.

In order to have integrability, I believe we must show that $A([v,w])$ is an eigenvector for any eigenvectors $v,w$ of $A$.  Say that $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are the eigenvalues associated to $v,w$, respectively.  The constant eigenvalue condition seems to imply that $$\nabla(Av) = A(\nabla v) = \lambda_1\nabla v,$$ but I do not understand how this implies the distribution is closed under Lie brackets.  In particular, it is clear from the above that $[Av,Aw] = \lambda_1\lambda_2[v,w]$, and it is also clear that the bracket is $A$-linear in both arguments separately.  With that said, why is it that $[v,w]$ is also an eigenvector of $A$?  I do not see it.

EDIT:  The operator $A$ is (as I understand it) not a priori a homomorphism of Lie algebras.  It is something related to the shape operator of an immersed submanifold.

Comment: By "linear operator on vector fields", do you mean fiberwise linear, i.e. a $(1,1)$ tensor? If so, the claim is false: Take any nonintegrable distribution, choose a metric, and consider the orthogonal projection onto that distribution.

Comment: Thanks for your comment; I understand your argument.  

Perhaps I simplified the claim too much for the sake of brevity.  The real scenario is from Yano and Ishihara's "Submanifolds with parallel mean curvature vector", in particular the discussion at the end of page 108. 

Here is a link to the manuscript. https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.jdg/1214430219

Unfortunately, I do not understand their argument well enough to summarize it better than I did above.  But I would appreciate your explanation if you happen to understand it.